# Inherit Permissions of a category when creating a channel in discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to create a channel that gives certain roles access and blocks out @everyone by default, but I also want it to work with categories, such as allowing other roles

```js
let specificOverwrites = [
                ...members,
                {
                    id: creatorRoleId,
                    allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel]
                },
                {
                    id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone.id,
                    deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel]
                }
            ];

            // Use specificOverwrites during channel creation
            const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create({
                name: allianceNameInput,
                type: ChannelType.GuildText,
                parent: alliancesCategory.id,
                permissionOverwrites: specificOverwrites
            });
```

The above is the code that I currently have which works, but it simply ignores category permissions. How can I make it work with category permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the `permissionOverwrites` of the parent category and add the mapped permissions to the `specificOverwrites` array.

```
let specificOverwrites = [
    ...members,
    {
        id: creatorRoleId,
        allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel]
    },
    {
        id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone.id,
        deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel]
    },
    ...alliancesCategory.permissionOverwrites.cache.map((p) => {
        return {
            id: p.id,
            allow: p.allow.toArray(),
            deny: p.deny.toArray(),
        };
    }),
];

// Use specificOverwrites during channel creation
const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create({
    name: allianceNameInput,
    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
    parent: alliancesCategory.id,
    permissionOverwrites: specificOverwrites
});
```